# downward scrolling jquery div - how to prevent it from pushing down the header infinitely?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have a content div that includes a "sidebar" div on the right side that is supposed to slide down as the visitor scrolls down the content. This all works fine, except that it also pushes down infinitely the footer below, so the visitor can never fully see the entire footer (which is quite big by itself).

How do I make the scrolling div stop where the (dark grey) content div ends?

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vTcqv/4/

And the full preview: http://jsfiddle.net/vTcqv/4/embedded/result/

Thank you very much for any advice :)

Comment: You're document height is throwing it off

Answer (score 0):

You're document height includes the footer and if I understand correctly, we want to stop at the footer. So instead of having your document height be this:

```
documentHeight = $(document).height();
```

Change it to also remove the size of the footer.

```
documentHeight = $(document).height() - $('#footer').height();
```

There is a slight issue where it doesn't go flush with the content div but I'm sure that it is easily fixable.

http://jsfiddle.net/vTcqv/6/

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Constrain your sidebar to its parent element, the #maincontainer div instead of the whole document.

Replace

```
documentHeight = $(document).height();
```

with

```
containerHeight = $("#maincontainer").height();
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/vTcqv/11/embedded/result/